# How to improve loss and avoid overfitting

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, accuracy, convolutional-neural-network, overfitting

I'm trying to build a 2 class image classifier using the architecture suggested in first part of this blog https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

My dataset has 1500 images of class1 and 500 images of class2. I created 4 copies of class2 to make the number of images same in both classes.

I also use ImageDataGenerator to augment images

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=True,
        featurewise_std_normalization=True,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.5,
        rotation_range=45,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True)
datagen.fit(train_imgs)
```

I'm using AdaDelta,RMSProp, SGD, Adam, AdaGrad optimizers and tried adding/removing Conv2D and Dense layers. Tried BatchNormalizationa and Dropout. The results are coming out almost same:

For first few epochs(about 20) training and validation errors keep reducing until log loss reaches about 0.4 (best I have got till now) after that the model starts to overfit and validation loss keeps increasing.

I know I can prevent overfitting by reducing the network complexity and adding dropouts but that reduces the training accuracy too.

Please suggest some tips to improve the accuracy and avoid overfitting.

Comment: Have you tried tuning L1 and L2 regularization?

Comment: Didn't try that. Should I try L1 L2 with or with out dropout and and batchnormalization ?

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with the software you are using but keep in mind: You EXPECT accuracy to drop if you reduce over fitting. It is not a bad thing. Over-fitting is essentially "fake accuracy".

Some good approaches in general to avoid over-fitting though: Use cross-validation, normalize your features, increase size of data-set and dont just increase your data-set by copying data.

Comment: Just to be clear, you expect *training* accuracy to decrease when you reduce overfitting.  Test accuracy will increase, which is, of course, the whole point.

Comment: Isn't cross-validation for assessing a model? How it could imporove the performance of the model?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to reduce over-fitting.

1. Use Dropout increase its value and increase the number of training epochs
2. Increase Dataset by using Data augmentation
3. Tweak your CNN model by adding more training parameters. Reduce Fully Connected Layers.
4. Change the whole Model
5. Use Transfer Learning (Pre-Trained Models)

Comment: Can you explain what adding more training parameters means?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 4) Change the whole Model ? Isn't any model good enough to approximate function by Universal Approximation theorem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dropout which will help in controlling the model to over train.
While using CNN,data-set plays an important role.The more data-set the more model can learn features from it.
You can divide your data-set in 3 parts.
Training ,testing and validation.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you can try to reduce overfitting:

1. Use batch normalization
2. add dropout layers
3. Increase the dataset
4. Use batch size as large as possible (I think you are using 32 go with 64)
5. to generate image dataset use [flow from data](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)
6. Use [l1 and l2 regularizes](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/Regularizer) in [conv layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D)
7. If dataset is big increase the layers in neural network.
8. USE callbacks  `tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau)

Hope this mat help, also plot the history graph of training to have a better understanding of your model.

Answer (score 0):

there some advice：
1、use the dropout
2、try to normalization.such as you can `optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate,weight_decay=0.1)` 
3、try to change the model
4、increase the number of the data
sometimes the some change you have do the better effect of the ML and DL you will get